# ignore headers text from raw text python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm working with the html pages using `BeautifulSoup4`. `html` files does contains `request headers` information at the top, how can I filter that out?

here is `html` file snippet

```
WARC/1.0
WARC-Type: response
WARC-Date: 2012-02-17T03:07:46Z
WARC-TREC-ID: clueweb12-0206wb-51-29582
WARC-Record-ID: <urn:uuid:546b127c-040e-4dee-a565-3a3f6683f898>
Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=response
Content-Length: 29032

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Connection: close
Date: Fri, 17 Feb 2012 03:07:48 GMT
Content-Length: 28332
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie:         chkvalues=ClmZLoF4xnHoBwiZnWFzYcCMoYB/fMxYfeeJl/zhlypgwivOzw6qnVBRWzf8f19O; expires=Wed, 15-Aug-2012 02:07:48 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: previous-category-id=11; expires=Fri, 17-Feb-2012 03:27:48
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="ctl00_headTag"><title>
```

I want to extract text between the `<html></html>` nothing else. When I try to do something like this.

```
with codecs.open(file, 'r', 'utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
        contents = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "lxml")
    for script in soup.find_all(["script", "style"]):  # to remove script style tags
        script.extract()
    try:
        raw_text = soup.find('html').text.lower()

    except AttributeError:
        pprint('{0} file is empty'.format(file))
```

in `raw_text` it fills up 
`"WARC/1.0\r\nWARC-Type: response\r\nWARC-Date: 2012-02-17T03:07:46Z....` like information, means it's adding headers into `raw_text`.

how can I remove that header thing from my raw text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP headers are separated from the body by two newlines, so you could use `\r\n\r\n` to split your data. However your file contains both the request and response, and it would be easier to use the beginning of the body as a separator.

```
try:
    contents = contents[contents.index('<!DOCTYPE'):]
except ValueError:
    contents = contents[contents.index('<html'):]
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "lxml")
```

Some html documents may not have a `DOCTYPE` declaration. In that case use `'<html'` as index after wrapping all in `try except` block.

Answer (score 0):

```
'\n'.join([e for e in raw_text.split('\n') if (e and e[0]=="<")])
```

You could use this list comprehension to make sure each line begins with a `<`